# How to declare a C array property in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How to declare a C array of integers as a property on an objective-c class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912016/declaring-properties-synthesizing-and-implementing-int-array-in-objective-c

Comment: is this you want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/912344/2629258

Comment: YES thanks couldn't find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476843/create-an-array-of-integers-property-in-objective-c

Comment: Please see my updated answer. stack based arrays will probably get cleaned after the method call. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int *array;
...
// somewhere in your code 
    int *gg = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    gg[1] = 1;
    gg[0] = 2;
    self.array = gg;
```

**UPDATE:**

> This is heap based array now to make sure it will not be deallocated. 
>   But don't forget to free it in dealloc `free(self.array)`

Comment: exactly what i was trying to achieve. the cleanest answer from all in other similar questions

Comment: great :)@NicolasManzini

Comment: You can't do this. When you leave the scope where `gg` was declared your `array` property will contain pointer to a deallocated part of memory. Best case scenario you will get trash instead of values you want. In case of `int *array` array must be allocated on heap using `malloc` or `new`.

Comment: the funny thing is I was reading about this heap/stack problem right now! :) i can fill it with 0s by doing gg[] = {0} ?

Comment: yep :) thanks to @creker for reminding :)